# Is it possible to hook a text box into a WordPress theme, via the functions.php file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently using a WordPress theme to create an ecommerce website.   I am looking to create a horizontal text box, with 3 columns, to appear directly beneath the Main Menu navigation.  Rather than edit the header.php file, and risk breaking the theme, is it possible to achieve this by hooking into the theme, via a functions.php file in the child theme or would thus be bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding "right after the main menu" is not something WordPress will be able to give you directly, no. Because, by definition, the structure of a page is a theme's responsibility.

That would be a perfect case for a child theme, and it would be my first choice. There you can safely override the index file (or header file, depending on how the theme is built) and add your html to it.

Another option a child theme might give you, is adding html through the theme's own filters and actions - but that will totally depend on your theme giving you such hooks.

Finally, if truly you want to add right after the main navigation, you might look at the [wp_nav_menu filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/): using that, it should be possible to first detect if you are looking at the main navigation or not, and if you are, append your own html. But frankly, I think the risk of breaking your layout is greater with that method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input and help MacPrawn.